# ASP MVC EditorTemplates for ComplexType

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I am a silent reader of stackoverflow and in almost all cases I find solution to my problems from others' posts from this website until yesterday when I got stuck on something and can't find a solution.

Here is a little explanation on my app architecture:

I have code-first entity model in a separate c# project and I am referencing it to my web project. I have following entities:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee();
    public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
    public DateTime? DegreeCompleted{ get; set; }
    public virtual University University { get; set; }
}
public class University 
{
    public University();
    public int UniversityId {get;set;}
    public short? TotalDegrees{ get; set; }
    public short? TempTotalDegrees{ get; set; }
}
```

On view side, I have a Home view with Index.cshtml which is referring `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/University.cshtml` as this:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveEmployee", new AjaxOptions
 { 
            HttpMethod="POST",
            OnBegin="disableSubmit",
            OnComplete = "enableSubmit",
            OnFailure = "enableSubmit",
            InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace
            }))
      {
      @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.EmployeeId)
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.University, new { EmployeeId = Model.EmployeeId})
```

here is how University.cshtml looks:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.UniversityId)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.TotalDegrees, new { @class="form-control", @min="5",@max="100",@type="number",@value=(Model.TotalDegrees.HasValue ? Model.TotalDegrees.Value : 5)})
```

on Index.cshtml, when I click on submit button it posts back the Employee object to server but

Employee.University.TotalDegrees is null, even though user fills in the value

If I remove `@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.UniversityId)` from University.cshtml, `Employee.University` comes as null on post.

I have tried to use `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.TotalDegrees)` and `@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.TotalDegrees)` but none of them seems to work

If I moved everyfrom from University.cshtml to main View, everything seems to work fine.

Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Probably not related, but do not attempt to override the `value` attribute - set the value of `TotalDegrees` in the controller before you send the model to the view. And do not use `x => Model` (capital M) which can result in exceptions depending on other code in your view

Comment: Your passing `new { EmployeeId = Model.EmployeeId}` as additional view data to the template suggesting your using it somewhere in the template - post the full code of the editor template. And show the actual html generated by your template - is the `name` attribute `name="University.TotalDegrees"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am passing viewdata but not using it at the moment. Yes name translates to University.TotalDegrees and id to University_TotalDegrees

Comment: Then there is something that you have not shown us, because the code you have shown will work fine. Show the controller method your posting to.

Comment: Stephen I have nothing fancy in there but just this

Comment: [HttpPost] public ActionResult SaveEmployee (Employee employee) {}

Comment: I have just copied your code and tested it. Apart from the obvious errors so it will compile (removing `public Employee();` and `public University();` from your classes), your code works fine and using `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TotalDegrees, new { @class="form-control",  @min="5", @max="100", @type="number" })` binds correctly when posting.

Comment: Could this possibly be because of having edmx in separate class lib and i am using EF directly as a model in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crap !!! spent 16 hours to identify that designer gave me this

```
               <form role='form'>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <input />
                </div>
               </form>
```

so apart from my own form, there was a form associated to each field in EditorTemplate and it was posting form to no where :(

Thanks Stephen for your help and sorry for wasting time :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you wrote wrong lambda `x => Model.TotalDegrees`. Just fix this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TotalDegrees, new { @class="form-control", @min="5",@max="100",@type="number",@value=(Model.TotalDegrees.HasValue ? Model.TotalDegrees.Value : 5)})
```